# C# Algorithm (big data) for finding duplicate rows across multiple columns and worksheets in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, algorithm, duplicates, vsto

I am trying to devise an algorithm for finding duplicate rows in an Excel file across multiple worksheets.

**Assume the following:**

1) the file can be extremely large. Consider a file that has 10 worksheets (each with 1,048,576 rows) and say 30 columns of data

2) the duplicate rows may not be on the same worksheet. For example Sheet1/Row20 may be a duplicate of Sheet5/Row123456

3) to determine if a row is duplicate of another,  1 or more of its columns could be used as a user-specified condition (its not always that all columns must be the same, the user could for example specify that a duplicate is when columns 2,3 and 5 are the same)

4) the order of the underlying data cannot be changed (no sorting the data first and then checking adjacent rows).

5) the algorithm must be memory efficient. Storing all the values of the columns of a row in a Dictionary will take up too much memory. Not all of the data can be stored in memory (read into .NET multidim arrays) at the same time since that would effectively double the memory usage since it is already stored in Excel.

6) the algorithm must minimize IO with the Excel object model. Continually retrieving a single row of data at a time (or performing some other built in Excel interop operation) from Excel can be slow.

So far I have had two different ideas for the Algorithm:

**Algorithm 1)**

a) Create a Dictionary< int, List< Tuple < int, int> > where the dictionary key is the hashvalue of the desired values in the columns in a particular row and List< Tuple < int, int > > is a list of worksheet index/row index that compute to that hash code

b)Read in a large chunk of the data from Excel at a time (say 50,000 rows) and fill up the Dictionary.

c)find all entries in the Dictionary where the List has a Count > 1 and then go through all the rows and check if there are in fact duplicates by reading the data from Excel again and comparing the actual values this time

**Algorithm 2)**

Similar to Algorithm 1 but use two (or maybe three) distinct and independent hash functions to create a Tuple < int, int > or Tuple < int, int, int > as the key for the Dictionary. If the hash functions are independent then there would be a near 0% probability that there is a collision at a specific key unless the rows are in fact equal. step 1c) could be omitted because of this.

To get the hashkey used in algo1, I would do something like this:

```
private int GetHashKey(List<object> columns)
{
        int hash = 23;
        foreach (var o in columns)
            hash = hash * 31 + o.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
}
```

If I wanted to do algorithm 2) I would need to define an extension method GetHashCode2() for object (or at least the possible return data types for Range.Value2 which are string, double, bool and int)

Can anyone think of a better solution?
What are people's thoughts on Algo1 vs Algo2?
If people think Algo2 is better, any idea how I code create a GetHashCode2() function that is efficient and robust and produces different hash codes than GetHashCode()?

Comment: If you want to read data 50k rows at a time then how you are going to find duplicates say from 4th row and 544444th row?

Comment: The Dictionary is used to determine potential duplicates. Read the first 50k rows and compute the hash values for each row and store them in the dictionary, read the next 50k rows and add their respective keys and values to the dictionary. Repeat until all the rows have been read. Finally check the Dictionary for any values (Which is a list of row numbers) with a count greater than 1 and thiose could be potential duplicates

Comment: Are you saying that it IS ok to store ALL of the hash values into a dictionary, but NOT the values of the cells themselves? If so, then this approach should work, however I would think that if the hash is used as your Dictionary key, you'll never get a count greater than 1 - you'll just have an error adding to the dictionary.

Comment: Also, have you thought about just loading all the data into PowerPivot and letting it do the hard work? It'll have no problems with handling millions of rows, will be very fast/performant. The only limitations would be compatibility regarding the versions of Excel.